# How to make customUI objects in xcode 4 for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I want to know how to make custom UI objects in iPhone ?

[image: this is where it shows the list of custom objects]

Answer (score 6):

You can't do custom objects for iPhone development yet.  That's for Mac development.

The closest you can get is to program your own custom component based on a UIView, then place a UIView in IB and change the type to your custom component.  It will then let you do any wiring needed and at runtime will embed an instance of your own class.  You cannot see the component in IB though, only an empty UIView....

Comment: Is there any reason why custom objects cannot be made for iPhone development ?

Comment: I'm not sure why Apple has not added support for this yet, XCode simply doesn't support it at this time.

Comment: Is there a tutorial related to the technique that you have mentioned.I would like to show a small view on the top of each view of my app and load a webview in it.

Comment: You can add a web view directly in IB, so for each screen of the app just add it to the top.

Comment: Okay, so for MAC development how do you use the "Custom Objects" panel as shown above?

Comment: I would submit that as a new question, I'm not trying to duck the question or get points, but instead think a new question could net you a more awesome response than I could give.