# I want to know how to make custom objects for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I would like to know how to create a custom UI object for iPhone in Xcode 4 .
How to  make an object which can be reused in any other iPhone applications ?

The listing of objects comes like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[its unavailable in iPhone only for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567673/how-to-make-customui-objects-in-xcode-4-for-iphone)